# What does the "-" symbol mean in the "Software and Upadates" Application

Tags: software-sources

Installed Ubuntu 20.04, I mean its a fresh Install..

Opened "Software and Updates" Application.. Selected the "Source Code".
I noticed that the "Source Code" Option I have selected is `-` symbol. Others above it are tick marks..

So is there anything different from the manually Selected "Source Code" Option with "out of the box tick marks" ?

[image]

If there is a difference, How to make it in line with the out of the box tick marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that not 100% of repositories have enabled source code component,
so the number of `deb-src ...` and number of `deb ...` are not equal
in the [*sources.list*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/sources.list.5.html)s for official Ubuntu repositories.

I would recommend to uncheck this `[ ] Source code` checkbox and then check it again `[v] Source code`.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the answer.. Can you eloborate on `deb-src . . .` And `deb . . .`

Comment: Check http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/sources.list.5.html for details.